# Phonegapで開発したcordovaアプリにおいて、iOS 9系でajax通信ができない

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

Phonegapでcordovaアプリを開発しています。

表題のとおり、iOS 9でajax通信ができません。
（iOS 10、iOS 11ではajax通信ができました。）

（Appleの非推奨ですが）
ひとまずajax通信をできるようにするためには、
*-Info.plistに

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key> 
<dict> 
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
</dict>
```

が記述されれば良いそうです。
（もし、この理解が間違っていれば、ご指摘お願いします。）

config.xmlに

```
 <access origin="*" />
 <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
 <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
 <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
 <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
 <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
 <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
 <allow-navigation href="*://*youtube.com" />
```

を記述したところ

\platforms\ios\myapp\myapp-Info.plist

には

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>*youtube.com</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
    </dict>
  </dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

が記載されました。

しかし、それでもiOS 9でajax通信ができません。

どうすればできるようになるのか、
ご存知の方、ご回答よろしくお願い致します。

また、他にも情報が必要であれば、ご指摘お願い致します。

ちなみにですが、

```
<allow-navigation href="*://*youtube.com" />
```

は、今回のアプリでyoutubeを視聴できるようにするため、
記述する必要があります。

---

**バージョン**

```
Phonegap Buiid : 8.0.0
cordova-iOS : 4.5.4
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/138745

Comment: ATS有効時に例外を指定する命令ですので、`NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`に`True`入れてATSを無効にするなら`NSExceptionDomains`はいらないのでは？無効にするなら、そもそも`ATS`の記述自体消した方がいい気がします…。

Comment: 確かにおっしゃるとおりですね。ただ、`NSExceptionDomains`を消してみましたが、やはりajax通信はできませんでした。

Comment: `NSExceptionDomains`を消すとYoutubeが見れなくなってしまいましたので、やはり必要でした。

Answer (score 0):

質問を読み返して気づいた点ですが、
Ajax通信を行っているドメインはYouTubeですか？
通信先のドメインも追加した方が良いと思います。
また、iOS9についてですがそれ以外についても設定を記載しました。
参考にして下さい。

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <!-- WebViewにおける制限(iOS10以上)：trueでATS無効 -->
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
    <!-- iTunes(AVFoundationFrameWorks)における制限(iOS10以上)：trueでATS無効 -->
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInMedia</key>
    <true/>
    <!-- ローカルリソースにおける制限(iOS10以上)：trueで読込許可 -->
    <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
    <true/>
    <!-- iOS9における制限 -->
    <!-- 指定したドメインに対し例外的に設定したATS項目を無効化する -->
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>allow.domain.name</key><!-- 例外ドメイン(複数指定可能)：Ajax通信を行うサーバのドメインを追加する -->
        <dict><!-- 直上のドメインに対する設定 -->
            <!-- TrueでHTTP通信を無条件で許可：ほかSSL無し接続・矛盾した証明書を無視 -->
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <!-- 前述の"NSExceptionDomains"で設定したドメインに対し全てのATSを無効化 -->
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```